# Check multiple objects in an array and compare when certain properties in the object meet criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

An example of my problem is like this:

```
const costsArray = [
  {Id: 0, type: 'store', location: ['101, 102, 103']},
  {Id: 1, type: 'cost', location: ['109, 110, 111'], value: 460},
  {Id: 2, type: 'cost', location: ['109, 110, 111'], value: 60000},
  {Id: 3, type: 'item', location: ['109, 110, 111'], value: 460},
  {Id: 4, type: 'cost', location: ['109, 110, 111'], value: 461}
]
```

There are multiple properties that are similar to each other here. What I am trying to achieve is: comparing all these objects, and if any objects have the type 'cost' *and* the same properties for 'location' then console.log saying Id: 1, 2, 4 have differing values.

what I have so far, not sure if right direction though

```
costsArray.forEach((x: any) => {
   if(x.type.name === "cost" && x.location.id === })
```

Comment: Where's your *code*? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't add what little code I had because I was stumped

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```js
const costsArray = [
  {Id: 0, type: 'store', location: '101, 102, 103'},
  {Id: 1, type: 'cost', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 460},
  {Id: 2, type: 'cost', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 60000},
  {Id: 3, type: 'item', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 460},
  {Id: 4, type: 'cost', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 461}
];

let costLocations = {};
for (let c of costsArray) {
  if (c.type = 'cost') {
    (costLocations[c.location] = costLocations[c.location] || []).push(c.Id);  
  }
}

for (let key in costLocations) {
  if (costLocations[key].length > 1) {
      console.log(costLocations[key] + " have different values")  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const costsArray = [
  {Id: 0, type: 'store', location: '101, 102, 103'},
  {Id: 1, type: 'cost', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 460},
  {Id: 2, type: 'cost', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 60000},
  {Id: 3, type: 'item', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 460},
  {Id: 4, type: 'cost', location: '109, 110, 111', value: 461}
];

console.log(
  /* only get items whose type is 'cost' */
  costsArray.filter(cost => cost.type === 'cost')
            /* find items whose value unique */
            .filter((item, i, filteredArray) => filteredArray.find(it => it.value === item.value && it.Id !== item.Id) === undefined)
            /* select only the value from that item */
            .map(item => item.Id)
);
```